# How to do Open Graph Images in a Vue JS SPA?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, facebook-opengraph, nuxt.js

I'm trying to include an open graph image in my VueJS Single Page Application.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Yields me this link preview:

[image: Link preview on facebook open graph]

I think I can just jam the open graph meta tags in the top of the page if I want all routes to return the same image, but I would like different pages to show different images.

I've tried https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta and https://github.com/ktquez/vue-head, but those don't seem to help, presumably because they inject the meta tags via JS after the page has loaded.

Is there any other way than prerendering with Nuxt or Vue SSR?

Comment: Netifly can automatically prerender your SPA pages, if you host it there.

Answer (score 3):

[prerender-spa-plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin) in conjunction with vue-head/vue-meta should do the trick for you! As long as you know all of your routes in advance, it will render index.html files that you can serve for the bots.

If you have dynamic content you will have to use `captureAfterDocumentEvent` or `captureAfterTime` in order to capture asynchronous content has been rendered.

If you need something more robust [Vuejs SSR](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/) might be a better option.

Comment: I don't know my routes in advance. I'm on firebase and was able to get this working by sticking a cloud function in front of my hosting and rendering out the open graph for the direct link. For anybody interested, you can check out my response to this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/33. Search for TheRoccoB on page.